# Copy cv::Mat to file descriptor on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, file-descriptor, mat

I'm trying to make a pipeline between c++, and python using file descriptor.
So I can copy image buffer (cv::Mat) to file descriptor ( in c++) and it can be used in python as well.

Actually, I already built a simple pipeline which was for only string.
But, in case of large size (eg. image of 640 * 480) pipeline didn't work as expected.

```
auto size = ::write(fd, buf, len);
```

In above, `write` didn't return, and it only wrote data of 65535 bytes.
And no exceptions and no errors.

Seems, this is a problem of limit of file descriptor, so how can I resolve this issue?
And is there any other way to achieve this? (pipeline for big data)

Best Regards.

**Updates**

This is part of code that creates pipes (file descriptor means a pipe).

`write` will be called in `read_loop` function.

```
    int main() 
{
    int pipe_cpp_to_py[2];
    int pipe_py_to_cpp[2];

    if (::pipe(pipe_cpp_to_py) || ::pipe(pipe_py_to_cpp))
    {
        std::cout << "Couldn't open pipes" << std::endl;
        ::exit(1);
    }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if ( pid == 0 )
    {
        ::close(pipe_py_to_cpp[0]);
        ::close(pipe_cpp_to_py[1]);
        std::ostringstream oss;

        oss << "export PY_READ_FD=" << pipe_cpp_to_py[0] << " && "
            << "export PY_WRITE_FD=" << pipe_py_to_cpp[1] << " && "
            << "export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=true && " // Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.
            << "python src/main.py";


        ::system(oss.str().c_str());
        ::close(pipe_py_to_cpp[1]);
        ::close(pipe_cpp_to_py[0]);

    }
    else if ( pid < 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "Fork failed." << std::endl;
        ::exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        ::close(pipe_py_to_cpp[1]);
        ::close(pipe_cpp_to_py[0]);
        read_loop(pipe_py_to_cpp[0], pipe_cpp_to_py[1]);
        ::close(pipe_py_to_cpp[0]);
        ::close(pipe_cpp_to_py[1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you say "file descriptor". what mechanism is it precisely? as an alternative I would suggest shared memory. that is also faster because no copying needs to happen.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please check out updates.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz would you explain me more about shared memory? Is it possible to share in both of c++ and python?

Comment: according to the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), the written size can be lower than the given count if the RLIMIT_FSIZE has a smaller soft/hard limit. I'd check that and also your `len` variable. 65535 is the limit of 16 bit unsigned integers.